# Click event not firing with copied anchor in new jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I have a click event that only allows anchor tags to work when they are double clicked. This works fine when the anchor tag is in the original tree but after the file in the tree is copied to another tree, the event isn't firing and makes the anchor tags work with a single click. Anyone know the reason to this? The anchor tag is exactly the same in the new tree. I have my code below:

```
$('.tree-link').click(function(){
    return false;
}).dblclick(function() {
    window.location = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

The original anchor tag before copying (fires event):

```
<a class="jstree-anchor  tree-link" href="#settings.html"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon fa fa-briefcase icon-state-success  jstree-themeicon-custom"></i>test</a>
```

the copied anchor tag in the new tree (doesn't fire event):

```
<a class="jstree-anchor  tree-link" href="#settings.html"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon fa fa-briefcase icon-state-success  jstree-themeicon-custom"></i>test</a>
```

The two anchor tags are exactly the same but I don't know why the other doesn't fire the click event... Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on using an anchor and just used a double click event while using window.location.href to change the page. This currently works fine for me. Here is the code if anyone is interested:

```
$('#tree').on("dblclick", function (event) {
var li = $(event.target).closest("li");
var node = $('#tree').jstree().get_node(li.attr('id'));
if(node.icon.indexOf("briefcase") != -1){
    window.location.href = "#settings.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because moving from tree to tree probably removed node from DOM and inserts it again.

Look at this:

```js
$('.myClass').click(function() {
  return false;
}).dblclick(function() {
  window.location = this.href;
});

$('.move').click(function() {
  var anchor = $('.myClass');
  anchor.remove();
  document.body.appendChild(anchor.get(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com"/ class="myClass">link</a>
<button class="move">Move link</button>
```

A solution to that problem is to use method `.on` of jQuery, which attach events to all elements that will be added to DOM in the future.

Comment: Sorry I realised that the problem is related to the jstree plugin I'm using and not the fact that the anchor tag has more than one class. The problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to see if this.href is accessible in the scope of your function? most likely you're referencing jquery instead of the object itself

try:

```
var self = this;
$('.myClass').click(function(){
    return false;
}).dblclick(function() {
    window.location = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this.href works when the original node is not copied, the problem I have is that the click event doesn't fire on the copied node

Comment: try using a unique id, might be that the listeners are wating on a previous found dom element to fire

Comment: if you want multiple objects to fire the same method you can always user  `$("#id_01 , #id_02 , #id_03").click()`

Comment: No that wouldn't be ideal since ids are automatically generated by the jstree plugin for copy and paste and that method could get messy really quick when the tree has more than one link.

Comment: have you tried using the double click directly? `$('.myclass'). dblclick(function(){  window.location = this.href; })`

Comment: I would need to use the click() to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag wouldn't I?

Comment: if you're launching routing through javascript, is there a reason to making it a anchor tag?, otherwise you could add to the anchor `href='javascript:void(0);'`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tree-link', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('single-click');
}).on('dblclick', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('double-click');
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vxm4quzz/1/

Also you're might interested in reading this: [jQuery eventDelegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: No still the same unfortunately... The original node will trigger the event but the copied node won't

Comment: @NiallMitch14 please recheck the answer, it's updated .

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it does go into the function now but prevent default or return false to prevent the hyperlink redirecting doesn't work now

Comment: @NiallMitch14 updated again. now if you remove `event.preventDefault()` it will open a new tab going to google ...

Comment: No that doesn't work... It is able to go into the function but prevent default is not preventing going to the new link. Not sure if js tree anchor tags behave differently

Comment: maybe also add `event.stopPropagation()` http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: Still nothing :/ I honestly have no idea... If it was a normal anchor tag this wouldn't have been a problem